# Create a variable in Multiple Dataframes in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I want to create a ranked variable that will appear in multiple data frames.
I'm having trouble getting the ranked variable into the data frames.

Simple code. Can't make it happen.

```
dfList <- list(df1,df2,df3)
for (df in dfList){
  rAchievement   <- rank(df["Achievement"])
  df[[rAchievement]]<-rAchievement
}
```

The result I want is for df1, df2 and df3 to each gain a new variable called rAchievement.

I'm struggling!! And my apologies. I know there are similar questions out there. I have reviewed them all. None seem to work and accepted answers are rare.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` with `transform` in a single line

```
dfList <- lapply(dfList, transform, rAchievement = rank(Achievement))
```

If we need to update the objects 'df1', 'df2', 'df3', set the names of the 'dfList' with the object names and use `list2env` (not recommended though)

```
names(dfList) <- paste0('df", 1:3)
list2env(dfList, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or using the `for` loop, we loop over the sequence of the `list`, extract the `list` element assign a new column based on the `rank` of the 'Achievement'

```
for(i in seq_along(dfList)) {
    dfList[[i]][['rAchievement']] <- rank(dfList[[i]]$Achievement)
  }
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you for solving with two approaches. Really well done!